# Getting "No qmlscene installed." warning in "QT CREATOR" on "Ubuntu"

Tags: qt, qt-creator

i added QTStatic to QT Versions, but i cant use this version to build and set in kits tab.

i uploaded screenshot below : (plz help)

[Versions Tab Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpaGB.jpg)

[Kits Tab Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TRye.jpg)

Comment: qmlscene is just a helper application for running qml-files without compiled QApplication. You can build it manually from the source. This does NOT prevent you from building your application. Did you compile Qt static yourself? Otherwise it probably wont be static version.

Answer (score 42):

I had the same issue under Debian Jessie. I fixed it by installing the `qtdeclarative5-dev` package.

Comment: This fixes the problem in Ubuntu 16.04 as well.

Comment: I have reported [bug #824334 against qtcreator](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=824334) suggesting that it recommends this package as it is otherwise hard to find what is needed (it only recommends `qtdeclarative5-dev-tools`, which is insufficient).

Comment: The fedora equivalent package is `qt5-qtdeclarative-devel`

Comment: Works on Stretch as well. Thanks.

Comment: Works on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.3 using `qt5-qtdeclarative-devel` as Thibaut suggested.

Comment: Also in debian 10 `sudo apt install qmlscene` not work and `qt5-qtdeclarative-devel` will solve that. Thank you.

Comment: This fixes the problem in Ubuntu 20.04 as well.

Comment: It is disheartening that this answer is still useful five years later.