# No qmlscene installed: why is a warning sign next to Qt version on Build&Run options

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I don't understand why there is a yellow warning sign next to my manually-added Qt version of `qmake`, i.e. `Qt 5.9.1 (qt5)`, hovering over the warning sign gives no additional info:

[image: Warning sign screen-shot]

In the above screen-shot, it is mentioned:

> No qmlscene installed

Suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36667532/3405291), I installed this but it couldn't help:

```
$ sudo apt install qtdeclarative5-dev
```

---

Why is there a warning? How can I resolve it? Will it affect my builds/runs in a crucial way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

QmlScene is an external QML preview application for Qt Quick 2 views. Qt Quick 1 has a tool called QmlViewer for same purpose. It seems to be packed separately on debian based system. Following command should get the package.

```
sudo apt-get install qmlscene
```

Comment: what about windows? is there solution for this warning on windows? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For those that didn't install GCC, you can try uninstalling QT and then re-installing but with GCC. This was my resolution which worked for me on Linux Mint 19 with QT 5.7.